# How to select a column containing dot in column name in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table which consists of column named "a.b"

```
q)t:([]a.b:3?10.0; c:3?10; d:3?`3)
```

How can we select column a.b and c from table t?
How can we rename column a.b to b?
Is it possible to achieve above two cases without functional select?

```
Failed attempts:
q)select a.b, c from t
'type
q)?[`t;();0b;enlist (`b`c!`a.b`c)]
'type
q)select b:a.b from t
'type
```

Comment: I don't think there is any legit way to do so. The best choice is to rename it.
That's an interesting case: ``flip`b`c!(flip t)`a.b`c`` - as you see no issue with retrieving column named `a.b` from flipped table (i.e. dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I hate answering any online forum question by refuting the premise, I really must here, **do not use periods in column names, it will cause trouble**. `.Q.id` exists to santise column names for a reason.

The primary reason that errors are encountered is that the use of dot notation in qSQL is reserved for the resolution of [linked columns](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/linking-columns/). We can see how this is actually working by parsing the query itself

```
q)parse "select a.b from tab"
?
`tab
()
0b
(,`b)!,`a.b // Here the referencing of a linked column b via a is occuring

// Compared to a normal select
q)parse "select b from tab"
?
`tab
()
0b
(,`b)!,`b
```

Other issues could crop up depending on future processing, such as q attempting to treat the column names as namespaces or operating on each part of the name with the dot operator.

Using dot notation in your column names will hamstring any further development, and force all other kdb users to use roundabout methods. The development will be slow and encounter many bugs.

I would advise that if periods must be included in the column, you create an API for external users to use to translate queries into the sanitised forms.

You can easily sanitise the whole table with `.Q.id`

```
q)tab:enlist `a.b`c`d!(1 2 3)
q)tab:.Q.id tab
q)sel:{[tab;cl] ?[tab;();0b;((),.Q.id each cl)!((),.Q.id each cl)]}
q)sel[tab;`a.b]
ab
--
1
```

Comment: I could relate to it, we call an api which returns a table with column having dot notation.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, `.Q.id t` will sanitise table column names if they aren't suitable for qSQL statements or performance in general.

```
 `a.b`c#t
```

will only work for multiple column selects and

```
 `a.b#t
```

will return a type error. However, you can get around this by enlisting the single item into the take operator, like so:

```
q)enlist[`a.b]#t
a.b
---------
4.931835
5.785203
0.8388858
q)(enlist`a.b)#t
a.b
---------
4.931835
5.785203
0.8388858
```

If you only need the values from a single column another option would be to use indexing, in this case, it would be `t[`a.b] ` which would return all values from the a.b column.

You could also mix these selection styles like so, but ultimately lose the column name from a.b:

```
q)select c,t[`a.b] from t
c x
----------
8 4.707883
5 6.346716
4 9.672398
```

In the query operation the `.` itself is used for foreign key navigation and it is throwing a type error as it cannot find any table relating to the foreign key it believes you have passed it.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following, using take `#` :

`` q) `a.b`c#t ``

```
a.b       c
-----------
4.931835  1
5.785203  9
0.8388858 5
```

To rename:

`` q) `b xcol t ``

```
b         c d  
---------------
4.931835  1 mil
5.785203  9 igf
0.8388858 5 kao
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Q.id` to rename any unselectable columns:

```
q).Q.id t
ab        c d
---------------
4.931835  1 mil
5.785203  9 igf
0.8388858 5 kao
```

Best to avoid dots in columns names and symbols in general, use underscore if you must.