# KDB - How to select a column with prefixed numbers?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of attributes that I am trying to pivot off of and while the pivot makes sense, several key attribute values I am successfully pivoting off of are prefixed with numbers (for sorting purposes). These are important attributes (there are several like this) that we want to pivot and report on.

I found a similar question here: [How to select a column containing dot in column name in kdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618764/how-to-select-a-column-containing-dot-in-column-name-in-kdb) and am when I sanitize the dictionary `.Q.id t` prefixed the columns with `a`

When I ran type on the returned value it returned `99h` so the pivot returns a dictionary.

I'm trying to leverage `` enlist(`1CODE)#t `` but to no avail as of yet.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
q) t

monthDate | 1CODE    2CODE     3CODE    4CODE    
----------| ------------------------------------
2022.01.01| 18.0054  0.1537228 4.116678 9.332936
2022.02.01| 17.87151 0.1527959 3.866393 9.685012
2022.03.01| 17.739   0.1518747 3.646734 10.00515
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables in kdb are just lists of dictionaries. Type 99h can be both a keyed table and a dictionary. You can still use qsql if you've sanitised your table:

```
q)select a1CODE from .Q.id t
a1CODE
--------
18.0054
17.87151
17.739
```

Another option is to use [xcol](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/#xcol) to rename your columns:

```
q)t:(`monthDate,`$1 rotate'string 1_cols t)xcol t
q)select CODE1 from t1
CODE1
--------
47.35547
75.21426
99.14374
```

Comment: Thank you Scott.  Yes, I was going down that route with sanitizing the table which seems to work for now.  This table was finishing and feeding our reporting so now a clean up step is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `colName#table` on a keyed table (`99h` is a keyed table in this case, though yes a keyed table is also a dictionary). So you would have to unkey the table first using `0!`

```
t:1!flip`monthDate`1CODE`2CODE!(2022.01.01 2022.02.01 2022.03.01;3?100.;3?10.);

q)((),`1CODE)#0!t
1CODE
--------
61.37452
52.94808
69.16099

q)((),`1CODE`2CODE)#0!t
1CODE    2CODE
------------------
61.37452 0.8388858
52.94808 1.959907
69.16099 3.75638
```

Comment: Thank you once again Terry.  I've not been able to get it to the above to work on my data (though unkeying obviously did but I'll keep trying.)  In the end I went with renaming using xcol and then finally landing on sanitizing the table but the column headers can vary widely based on the data processed. The table is sent to .NET to feed into a chart so while its simple to trim the first character, its a hassle if the column begins with a letter.  So frustrating as our data sources commonly have these numeric prefixed column.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by pivoting off of at the beginning, but an issue that sticks out to me is that the enlist function should use square brackets - rather than the round ones in in your post. So the code you want is:

```
  enlist[`1CODE]#t
```

Comment: thanks xxPJFxx....what i mean is I am performing a pivot using on  table to take a column of attributes (1CODE, 2CODE, 3CODE, etc) and pivot so these categories are now column headers. Per comments in this chain, KDB doesn't like column headers with numeric prefixes. : Here is the pivot that renders the table I posted in the original thread. 
` P: asc exec distinct CATEGORY from t;
  t: exec P!(CATEGORY!Metric)P by monthDate:monthDate from t;`